# how do I show $\frac{1}{\sum_{\tau=1}^t\lambda^{t-\tau}} = \frac{1-\lambda}{1-\lambda^t}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show that $\frac{1}{\sum_{\tau=1}^t\lambda^{t-\tau}} = \frac{1-\lambda}{1-\lambda^t}$ ?
Any help on how to get started will be appreciated
A very long derivation just states that this is true and in the description of the algorithm it says that $\lambda$ should be between 0 and 1, but then again says that for practical purposes $\lambda$ is chosen as 1, but I think the above equation cannot be true for $\lambda=1$

Comment: You are correct that the equation is not true (in fact doesn't make sense) for $\lambda=1$. The equation is the reciprocal of the geometric sum formula, which itself isn't too hard to swallow: distribute out the product $(\lambda-1)(\lambda^{t-1}+\cdots+\lambda+1)$ and see what it looks like.

Comment: Oh I see now; it's just the inverse of the formula for sum of geometric series with the first term equal to 1, corresponding to $\tau=t$ ; Thank you very much

Comment: @user13267: please post your answer and accept it so the question doesn't stay unanswered.  You could see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/policy-on-accepting-my-own-answer) for the site policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $t-r=s, r=1\implies s=t-1$ and $r=t\implies s=0$

$$\sum_{1\le r\le t}\lambda^{t-r}=\sum_{0\le s\le t-1}\lambda^s $$

Now use the summation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) of Geometric series

Comment: Thank you; by the way it should be $\lambda^s$ on the RHS; for some reason the website is not allowing me to make that edit

Comment: @user13267, thanks for your observation